# Generics and variance in Beam DoFn using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, apache-beam

I'm building a simple ETL pipeline using Apache Beam and Kotlin, where I'm trying to create a kind of `Either` type:

```
@DefaultCoder(SerializableCoder::class)
sealed class Result<out T> : Serializable {

    class Valid<out T>(val value: T) : Result<T>()

    class Invalid(val reason: String): Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Which is to be used for instance like this:

```
abstract class MapFunction<T, U> : DoFn<Result<T>, Result<U>>() {

    abstract fun map(item: T) : Result<U>

    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(context: ProcessContext) {
        val input = context.element()

        val output = when (input) {
            is Result.Valid -> map(input.value)
            is Result.Invalid -> input
        }

        context.output(output)
    }
}
```

This way I can keep track of all invalid results and output them at the end of my pipeline. The problem is that when I build a basic Pipeline I encounter the following cryptic error (formatted for readability):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
nl.sanderp.beam.functions.LyricsEnricher, 
@ProcessElement processElement(ProcessContext), 
@ProcessElement processElement(ProcessContext), 
parameter of type DoFn<Result<Song>, Result<Song>>.ProcessContext at index 0: 
ProcessContext argument must have type DoFn<Result<? extends Song>, Result<? extends Song>>.ProcessContext
```

I tried using the `@JvmWildcard` annotations as mentioned [in the Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics), but that only results in more errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.Types$WildcardTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this snippet working, if it's at all possible.

For reference, here's how the above code is called:

```
class LyricsEnricher(private val resourceFactory: ResourceFactory) : MapFunction<Song, Song>() {

    private lateinit var dao: LyricsDao

    @Setup
    fun setup() {
        dao = resourceFactory.get(ResourceFactory.Key.LYRICS_DAO)
    }

    override fun map(item: Song): Result<Song> {
        dao.findLyrics(title = item.title, artist = item.artist)?.also {
            return Result.Valid(item.copy(lyrics = it))
        }

        return Result.Invalid("No lyrics found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the type of the Invalid class is incorrect when using it with `out` like this.

Your beam map function is of type `MapFunction<T, Result<U>>` but you don't specify `U` anywhere, except inside the Sealed class where it becomes either(pun intended) `T` or `Nothing`.

If you change the type of `Invalid<Nothing>` to `Invalid<T>` and thus making the type of your map to `MapFunction<T, Result<T>>` beam seems to be oke with it.

Comment: Yes, the key was removing `out` parameter everywhere. Just goes to show: not all hints from Intellij are worth listening to...